# wordpress hook before update user

Tags: wordpress

I have a custom field on user profiles on the admin side.
I would like to be able to check the value of this custom field an display a message in some cases.
I looked at the wordpress documentation, read about the *profile_update* hook, but it fires after the update.
And besides I wonder how I could display a message.
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Ok so I used the following hooks to add the fields

```
add_action( 'show_user_profile', 'add_custom_user_profile_fields' );
add_action( 'edit_user_profile', 'fb_add_custom_user_profile_fields' );
```

and to check before update

```
add_action( 'personal_options_update', 'save_custom_user_profile_fields' );
add_action( 'edit_user_profile_update', 'save_custom_user_profile_fields' );
```

Answer (score 0):

**checkout this codex link it useful for you**

https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/personal_options_update